# How to clear netbeans output with code

Tags: java, netbeans

I was wondering if there was some sort of command I could output that would clear the netbeans output window? I just want the current output to clear, but still have the ability to output more after clearing at run time. Something similar perhaps to BlueJ's:

```
System.out.print('\u000C');
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> I was wondering if there was some sort of command I could output that would clear the netbeans output window?

No, not with a standard console. To do this you need to create either a Swing GUI and clear your text component, use another GUI such as SWT, or use a non-standard 3rd party console.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Netbeans,
use this method:

```
public void clear() throws AWTException {
    Robot rob = new Robot();
    try {
        rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); // press "CTRL"
        rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L); // press "L"
        rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L); // unpress "L"
        rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); // unpress "CTRL"
        Thread.sleep(1000); // add delay in milisecond, if not there will automatically stop after clear
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

add `import java.awt.AWTException;`
`import java.awt.Robot;`
`import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;`